# IIS Site Binding without SP Alternate Access Mapping

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

I have SharePoint Server 2010, and WebApp with site collection http://aa.contoso.com
when i **add IIS Site Binding** http://bb.contoso.com and **HH in DNS** but **Without** adding **Alternate Access Mapping** and the result is "**i can browse bb.contoso.com**" but **can NOT edit the site contents**. it happen  without having SP Alternate Access Mapping. I think it should not work that way. anyone has explaination?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like your SharePoint web application and Site Collection to respond correctly, you should extend the web application and use alternate access mapping.

**Reference**

- [How Do I: Configure an Alternate Access Mapping in SharePoint 2010?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/Video/ff679917)
- [Server Name Mapping and Alternate Access Mapping (AAM)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/enterprisesearch/archive/2010/05/28/server-name-mapping-and-alternate-access-mapping-aam.aspx)